# Android - SQLite how to get duplicates by two columns?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a problem - I can not apply this code in my database because of the line:

```
card = player_card.card
```

This line is very important in the request. It works well in Access and others, but in Android, it does not work. The application does not respond and does not even produce an error.

What do you advise? Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT * FROM player_card
WHERE email 
In (SELECT email FROM player_card As Tmp
   GROUP BY email, card 
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND card = player_card.card)
   ORDER BY email;
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/9dd08/16)

---

### Edited in response to answer from MikeT

Thank you so much! You really helped me get out of infinite circle (for (;;)). When I put your code into my app ... result is identical - app doesn't work. But why? ... This SQL code doesn't work with big databases on Android - my current base contains 12 k rows and 17 columns. Mobile hardware is too weak to operate with such tasks. When I reduce my database to 3 k - the code runs around 1 minute. At the end, I understood two things:

Codes like

```
card = player_card.card
```

cannot be used for big Android databases;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have something wrong elsewhere, the code works fine on android, as per (*sql copied into the **logIt** method*) :-

```
public class DBHelper001 extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "db";
    public static final int DBVERSION =1;

    public static final String TABLE_PLAYER = "player_card";
    public static final String COL_PLAYERCARD_CARD = "card";
    public static final String COL_PLAYERCARD_EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String COL_PLAYERCARD_REGION = "region";
    public static final String COL_PLAYERCARD_Q = "quantidade";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public DBHelper001(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase(); //<<<<<<<<<< when helper is instantiated will force on Create and thus the logIt method to run.
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        mDB = db;
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_PLAYER + "(" +
                COL_PLAYERCARD_CARD + " TEXT, " +
                COL_PLAYERCARD_EMAIL + " TEXT, " +
                COL_PLAYERCARD_REGION + " TEXT," +
                COL_PLAYERCARD_Q + " INTEGER," +
                "PRIMARY KEY (" +
                COL_PLAYERCARD_EMAIL + "," +
                COL_PLAYERCARD_REGION + "," +
                COL_PLAYERCARD_CARD + ")" +
                ")"
        );
        //<<<<<<<<<< Add some test data
        insertPlayerCard("card1","a@x.id","EU",1);
        insertPlayerCard("card2","a@x.id","EU",1);
        insertPlayerCard("card1","a@x.id","US",1);
        //<<<<<<<<<< INVOKE THE LOGIT METHOD >>>>>>>>>>
        logIt();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public long insertPlayerCard(String card, String email, String region, long quantitade) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_PLAYERCARD_CARD,card);
        cv.put(COL_PLAYERCARD_EMAIL,email);
        cv.put(COL_PLAYERCARD_REGION,region);
        cv.put(COL_PLAYERCARD_Q,quantitade);
        return mDB.insert(TABLE_PLAYER,null,cv);
    }

    //<<<<<<<<<< THE LOGIT METHOD RUNS QUERY AS COPIED AND REPORTS ROWS EXTRACTED >>>>>>>>>>
    public void logIt() {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM player_card " +
                "WHERE email " +
                "In (SELECT email FROM player_card As Tmp " +
                "   GROUP BY email, card " +
                "   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND card = player_card.card) " +
                "   ORDER BY email;";
        Cursor csr = mDB.rawQuery(sql,null);
        Log.d("RESULT","Number of rows extracted = " + String.valueOf(csr.getCount()));
        csr.close();
    }
}
```

**Simply instantiating and instance (if no database exists) runs the `logIt` method, which returned :-**

> ```
> 12-08 05:31:50.247 2049-2049/? D/RESULT: Number of rows extracted = 2
> ```

---

### Additional re edit to original question

It's not that you can't do it on Android, you can BUT it takes time.

In short the database above was loaded with 20997 rows and the query applied 3 times :-

- 1st to compensaste for caching/initial run issues
- 2nd being the 1st test run.
- 3rd after creating an index on the card column.

Each run worked BUT each took 20 minutes (on an emulated device, which I believe may be faster than some real devices).

- Note all run in a thread so as to avoid the ANR (Android Not responding, perhaps this being your issue)

results logged as :-

```
12-09 02:02:33.325 3702-3715/so53646027.so53646027 D/THREADREPORT: Started at (getting row count)2018-12-09 00:57:35.609+0000
        Number of Rows in player_card is 20997 at 2018-12-09 00:57:35.633+0000
        Finished Run to ignore chacheing effects at 2018-12-09 01:19:04.769+0000
        Finished Test Run without Index (started creating index on card column) at 2018-12-09 01:40:54.147+0000
        Finished Creating Index at; Starting Test Run with Index at 2018-12-09 01:40:54.223+0000
        Finished 2nd Test Run (now dropping index) at 2018-12-09 02:02:33.321+0000
        Finished at 2018-12-09 02:02:33.328+0000
```

I then copied the database and ran the exact same query (once) in Navicat (Not the slowest PC on earth here) it took a fraction under **6 minutes to run**.

From other testing it's clearly the `card = player_card.card` that's the core issue. Moving it to be a WHERE clause, significantly reduces query time to what I believe is a manageable/acceptable time e.g. :-

```
12-09 06:09:54.501 4845-4858/so53646027.so53646027 D/THREADREPORT: Started at (getting row count)2018-12-09 06:09:50.474+0000
        Number of Rows in player_card is 20997 at 2018-12-09 06:09:50.477+0000
        Finished Run to ignore chacheing effects at 2018-12-09 06:09:51.858+0000
        Finished Test Run without Index (started creating index on card column) at 2018-12-09 06:09:52.969+0000
        Finished Creating Index at; Starting Test Run with Index at 2018-12-09 06:09:53.048+0000
        Finished 2nd Test Run (now dropping index) at 2018-12-09 06:09:54.499+0000
        Finished at 2018-12-09 06:09:54.505+0000
```

About 1.5 seconds, with the same results as reported in the full logging :-

```
12-09 06:09:51.853 4845-4858/so53646027.so53646027 D/RESULT: Number of rows extracted = 7368
12-09 06:09:51.853 4845-4858/so53646027.so53646027 D/THREADREPORT: Finished Run to ignore cacheing at 2018-12-09 06:09:51.857+0000
12-09 06:09:52.965 4845-4858/so53646027.so53646027 D/RESULT: Number of rows extracted = 7368
12-09 06:09:52.965 4845-4858/so53646027.so53646027 D/THREADREPORT: Finished 1st Test RUN (not indexed, now building Index) at 2018-12-09 06:09:52.969+0000
12-09 06:09:53.045 4845-4858/so53646027.so53646027 D/THREADREPORT: Index created (starting 2nd Test Run) at 2018-12-09 06:09:53.048+0000
12-09 06:09:54.493 4845-4858/so53646027.so53646027 D/RESULT: Number of rows extracted = 7368
12-09 06:09:54.493 4845-4858/so53646027.so53646027 D/THREADREPORT: Finished 2nd Test RUN (dropping Index) at 2018-12-09 06:09:54.499+0000
12-09 06:09:54.501 4845-4858/so53646027.so53646027 D/THREADREPORT: Finished at 2018-12-09 06:09:54.505+0000
12-09 06:09:54.501 4845-4858/so53646027.so53646027 D/THREADREPORT: Started at (getting row count)2018-12-09 06:09:50.474+0000
        Number of Rows in player_card is 20997 at 2018-12-09 06:09:50.477+0000
        Finished Run to ignore chacheing effects at 2018-12-09 06:09:51.858+0000
        Finished Test Run without Index (started creating index on card column) at 2018-12-09 06:09:52.969+0000
        Finished Creating Index at; Starting Test Run with Index at 2018-12-09 06:09:53.048+0000
        Finished 2nd Test Run (now dropping index) at 2018-12-09 06:09:54.499+0000
        Finished at 2018-12-09 06:09:54.505+0000
```

i.e. Throughout I have consistently got the 7368 rows returned.

As such I believe you can use/convert :-

```
public void logIt() {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM player_card " +
            "WHERE email " +
            "In (SELECT email FROM player_card As Tmp " +
            "   WHERE card = player_card.card " +
            "   GROUP BY email, card " +
            "   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) " +
            "   ORDER BY email;";
    Cursor csr = mDB.rawQuery(sql,null);
    Log.d("RESULT","Number of rows extracted = " + String.valueOf(csr.getCount()));
    csr.close();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You really helped me get out of infinite circle (for (;;)). When I put your code into my app ... result is identical - app doesn't work. But why? ... This SQL code doesn't work with big databases on Android - my current base contains 12 k rows and 17 columns. Mobile hardware is too weak to operate with such tasks. When I reduse my database to 3 k - the code runs arond 1 minute. At the end, I understood two things:

1. Codes like
card = player_card.card

cannot be used for big Android databases;

Comment: 2. You are realy very good adviser! You have found some time to take this piece of code and test it either it was correct or not. You helped me to dispel my doubts and start to search for another possible solution. It seems, I have found one which I plan to test now. I'll be happy to get any advise from you.

Comment: The second request is much faster than the first. 
In the current database, where 12 k rows this request processed 38 duplicates in a little more than 1 minute. Great, but even that is slow considering the task at hand. For example, 
String query =  "SELECT * FROM player_card" +
                " GROUP BY email, card " +
                " HAVING COUNT(email) > 1 AND COUNT(card) > 1" +
                " ORDER BY email, card;";
this query in the current database works instantly without connecting threads. But it gives only a duplicate (one line of two matching rows).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest to run the query part by part if you are worried about big databases. Here are some suggestions for you.

- You might consider having proper indexes in your database. If the email addresses are unique, just put a unique constraint on the email address column. This will significantly reduce the database operation cost. To learn more about indexing, please [check the tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_indexes.htm) here.
- You may consider querying the result part by part. First, you might consider gathering the results of the second part of your overall query in a cursor, then you can consider iterating the cursor to check if the performance improved or not.
- Finally, and most importantly, in case of long database query operations, always try to run the query in an `AsyncTask` so that it does not freeze your UI thread. I think the time-consuming database operation is the reason behind freezing your application. Here is a [good start on learning](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html) how to run your big tasks in a separate thread other than the UI thread.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, but this database is not my - it's user's. My program operates user's table kind of *.xlsx. I cannot put into it additional columns. The user deletes them. Your second advice really helpful. I test it now. AsyncTask didn't help - the program hangs.

Comment: It would be great if you could share the code where you tried `AsyncTask`. Please edit your question and put the code there. I will be very happy to look into that. The `AsyncTask` should do the trick as far as I can think of.

Comment: I think this is another topic, for example: AsyncTask and its proper use, but I will think about it. Any way, Mark L. Murphy says that AsyncTask is not a panacea for any slowdowns in the program.